# Closing socket after subprocess.Popen leaves socket in TIME_WAIT as long as child process is still running

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, subprocess

On Windows 7:

Given this server code:

```
# in server.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    serversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # uncommenting this won't help
    #serversock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    serversock.bind(('',8888))
    serversock.listen(5)

    # accept and receive dummy data from client
    clientsock,address = serversock.accept()
    data = clientsock.recv(1024)

    # as long as calc.exe is running, I can't do this again
    subprocess.Popen(r"c:\windows\system32\calc.exe")

    # letting client close first still won't help
    time.sleep(3)

    # closing won't help either
    clientsock.close()
    serversock.close()
```

And the client code

```
# in client.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8888))
    s.sendall('Hello, world')
    # close early to help prevent TIME_WAIT on server, but doesn't help
    s.close()
```

Running server first then client will launch the calculator app.

**While the calculator app is still running, I can't run server again**. It will complain about

```
python server.py (ok)
python client.py (ok)
python server.py (boom!)
socket.error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

**If I close the Calculator app, running server is ok again...**
This does not happen on Mac.

Enabling SO_REUSEADDR will only make the error go away, but the server is unreachable from the client.

In the example above, I specifically let the **client close first** so that the server socket don't go into TIME_WAIT.

So the questions:

1. Am I running into the TIME_WAIT problem on the server?
2. Are any sockets/filedescriptors left unclosed in the server?
3. Why SO_REUSEADDR won't help in this case? could the client be coming from the same port?
4. Could the child process be hanging on to some descriptors?
5. What can I do about this?

**The SOLUTION:**

The problem IS with the parent process of Calculator holding on to some file descriptor.
So adding close_fds=True to the Popen will ensure everything is released properly.

```
subprocess.Popen(r"c:\windows\system32\calc.exe", close_fds=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Closing socket after subprocess.Popen leaves socket in TIME_WAIT as long as child process is still running

No it doesn't. It leaves it in TIME_WAIT for a fixed amount of time, 2 or 4 minutes. After the close it has nothing to do with the child process at all.

Comment: It won't release the socket (at least in windows). close_fds=True fixes this, and with that set, I don't even need SO_REUSEADDR.